# Netbeans: JButton Button cant set visible

Tags: java, netbeans

Dialog Code:

```
d1=new JDialog(this,"Help Menu",true);
    // Set size
    d1.setSize(500,180);

    // Set some layout
    d1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    d1.add(new JLabel("<html>Thank you for using the poster ordering system. <br> To begin, please select your desired poster size using the option menu provided. <br> Next, choose your desired poster style. <br> Now you can choose your quantity and background colour for your poster. <br> you are now finished! Your price will be displayed at the bottom right of the screen. <br> The pricing will show prices with and without VAT for your convenience.<br></html>"));
    JButton button = new JButton("close");
    d1.setVisible(true);




    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            dispose();

        }

    });
```

It says it has reached the end of the file before parsing, and wont show the "close" button on the help dialog. When I add "JButton.setVisible(true);" it says: "non-static method setVisible(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
I am new to Java and this is confusing me now!

Answer (score 1):

replace the following code :

```
JButton button = new JButton("close");
```

with this one :

```
static JButton button = new JButton("close");
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Any ideas for the "Reached end of file before parsing" ?

Comment: "illegal start of expression" comes up when I try that one!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your button to JDialog:

```
d1.add(button);
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks, still struggling with the bottom bit ( }); ) as it says: "Reached end of file before parsing?

Comment: @PhilMarsh did you close you class with "}" ?